# Client side js file is not working | node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So I just made a HTML page added a script tag with src to a js file and sent the HTML file as response with node js using HTTP module.
But the js file is not working and when I checked the network tab I saw js file is received as text/html file.

Following are the js and html codes.

Server code with node js

```js
const http = require('http') ;
const file = require('fs') ;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    
    file.readFile('public/login.html', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err ;
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}) ;
        res.write(data) ;
        res.end() ;
    })
}) ;

server.listen(5000) ;
```

front end code : login.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <script defer src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="email" name="user" id="user">
        <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
        <button type="submit" name="button" value="login">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

now when I load the page at localhost:5000, js does not execute and it's received as text/html.

Comment: Why not then make the type text/javascript instead of html?

Comment: What do you mean by "js does not execute". Do you expect idex.js to execute on the NodeJS Server instead of browser? That's not going to happen for sure unless you use a headless browser on your NodeJS API end.

Comment: @jae.phoenix how is that done. I'm a newbie...

Comment: @sribasu so my index.js is just `alert("hellow world") ;`. but when i go to localhost:5000 ther's no alert. but when I load the login.html with its absolute path in browser the alert is working

Comment: Side note: You'll see `if (err) throw err;` in Node.js callbacks a lot. It's rarely if ever the correct thing to do. Instead, you should handle the error (for instance, by sending a response with status code 500 or 404 or ...).

Comment: @me.nkr you should be able to access the index.js file using the url http://localhost:5000/js/index.js You need to make arrangements in your nodejs code for that. Until your Nodejs code allow accessing the Js file using the above url, your html page won't be able to download and run it. Currently, your nodejs code just allows accessing the html file, not the js file.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the tip. I do always handle errors is the final form, but anyway thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser will receive the HTML, see the `script` tag, and request `js/index.js` from your server. But your server **only** sends your HTML file. It doesn't pay any attention to what the browser requested, it just always sends back the HTML. So the script is never sent to the browser, so the browser can't execute it.

Your server code needs to look at `req` to determine what was requested (looking at [`url`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url), etc.), and send an appropriate response, rather than always sending back the same content.

Here's a fairly simple example that handles `/`, `/login.html`, and `/js/index.js` paths (making the first two synonyms):

```
const http = require('http');
const file = require('fs');

const FILENAME_404 = "public/404.html";

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    let filename = null;
    let contentType = "text/html";
    let status = 200;

    // What did the browser ask for?
    switch (req.url.toLowerCase()) {
        case "/":
        case "/login.html":
            // The login page
            filename = "public/login.html";
            break;
        case "/js/index.js":
            // The JavaScript file
            filename = "public/js/index.js";
            contentType = "text/javascript";
            break;
        default:
            // Something we don't support -- send a 404
            filename = FILENAME_404;
            status = 404;
            break;
    }

    sendFile(res, filename, contentType, status);
});

function sendFile(res, filename, contentType, status, callback) {

    file.readFile(filename, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            // Couldn't read the file, send a 404
            if (filename !== FILENAME_404) {
                sendFile(res, FILENAME_404, "text/html", 404);
            } else {
                // Couldn't even find the 404 file, send a minimal plaintext 404
                res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
                res.write("The requested resource does not exist on this server.");
                res.end();
            }
        } else {
            res.writeHead(status, {"Content-Type": contentType});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        }
    });
}

server.listen(5000);
```

**Note:** This is just an example. If you're going to build anything of any size, you'll want more structure than this. You might look at [Express](https://expressjs.com/) or [Koa](http://koajs.com/) or others that handle more of the HTTP plumbing, URL routing, etc. for you and have modules available for other things as well.

Comment: I am seeing index.js recived as text/html in network tab. so it's not the actual js file ?

Comment: can you please explain your answer a bit more. I am a newbie so it would be very helpful

Comment: @me.nkr - Right, is isn't, it's your HTML file.

Comment: @me.nkr - I've updated the answer to show a basic example. FWIW, it's important when starting out to do a **lot** of reading, experimentation, looking for examples, etc. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thanks man I got it now. So req.url contains files requested by the client side right ?

Comment: @me.nkr - It contains the URL the browser sent. Basically, what you see in the address bar but without the protocol ("scheme") and host.

Comment: hey is there any resources where I can read how requests work. I just used `console.log(req.url) ;` and it logged three strings. I was expecting an object or an array. But it logged three stings one under one. So does req.url return a string like "/ \n/a_file \n/another_file" ? or does itt run again and again till all file names are printed ? Just out of curiosity

Comment: @me.nkr - It's a simple string with no newlines in it. If you look in the network panel in the devtools in the browser, the browser is making three requests to your server. You're logging `req.url` each time, so you see three of them. The reason for two of the requests is obvious: You're going to the HTML, and the HTML loads the JavaScript. The reason for the third is less obvious: Browsers automatically request `/favicon.ico` in order to get an icon (if the site provides one) to show next to bookmarks, etc.

Comment: So each time browser requests a file/resource the `httpServer.on('request' , (req, res) => { // code here });` is fired ?

Comment: @me.nkr - Yes. It says almost exactly that in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request): *"Emitted each time there is a request."*